# Как предоставить форме доступ к закрытым полям класса?

Tags: c++-cli

Здравствуйте!

Делал лабораторную работу по программированию, и решил после того как сделал все задания добавить UI

В общем, у меня есть класс Matrix

```
class Matrix {
   int x;
   int y;
   double **matrix;
public:
   Matrix(int _x, int _y);
   Matrix(const Matrix &m);
   void fill();
   void fillRand();
   void showMatrix();
   Matrix& operator=(const Matrix &m);
   Matrix operator+(const Matrix &m);
   Matrix operator-(const Matrix &m);
   Matrix operator*(const Matrix &m);
   Matrix operator/(double number);
   friend Matrix& operator+=(Matrix &m1, const Matrix &m2);
   friend Matrix& operator-=(Matrix &m1, const Matrix &m2);
   friend Matrix& operator*=(Matrix &m1, const Matrix &m2);
   friend Matrix& operator/=(Matrix &m1, double number);    
   ~Matrix();
};
```

Как вы поняли, лаба по перегрузке операторов и по дружественным функцям.

Так вот, когда делаешь интерфейс, то генерируется класс,

```
public ref class UI : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
```

который никак не хочет дружить с моим классом Matrix :(

доступ к приватным полям закрыт

Есть возможность получить доступ к этим полям, или надо делать какие то "гетеры/сетеры"?

Comment: @hundermind Непонятно, что вы хотите. Это же вы сами написали свой класс, то какие проблемы? Делайте с ним что хотите.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Я хочу иметь доступ к приватным полям класса Matrix из класса UI

Comment: Имейте. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  проблема в том что НЕ ИМЕЮ

Comment: Да вы даже не пробовали, наверное. Главное начать, а там глядь - и уже имеешь доступ. :)

Answer (score 1):

Или перенести поля в public:

```
class Matrix {
public:
   int x;
   int y;
   double **matrix;
   [...]
};
```

Или делать getter/setter:

```
class Matrix {
   int x;
   int y;
   double **matrix;
public:
   [...]
   void setX(int x);
   void setY(int y);
   int getX();
   int getY();
   double ** getMatrix();
};
```

Ещё можно почитать про дружественные функции.

Я уже давно с C++ не работал, но вроде если определить класс как дружественный, то он будет иметь доступ к полям классам:

```
class Matrix {
   int x;
   int y;
   double **matrix;
public:
   [...]
   friend class UI; // теперь класс UI имеет доступ ко всем полям класса Matrix 
};
```

Comment: их никак не получается подружить :/